# Chrome autofill is populating multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have the following HTML.

When you choose an email to autocomplete, Chrome populates **all** of the input fields with the same address - overwriting any existing data. what am i missing?

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Email addresses: </label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="email" name="recipient-0">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="email" name="recipient-1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="email" name="recipient-2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Request
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: [This is a known bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c29)

Comment: I suggest looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill